# Error: std: out_of_range

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en introducir una palabra y rellenar un array con cada letra de la palabra. No obstante sale este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int const TAM_MAX=5;

typedef enum{A,B,C,D,E}tLetra;
typedef tLetra tArray[TAM_MAX];


int main()
{
    tArray array;
    string palabra;
    char letra;
    cout << "Introduzca una palabra de 5 cifras:";
    cin >> palabra;
    for(int i=0; i<TAM_MAX; i++)
    {
        letra=palabra.at(i);
        if(letra=='a' || letra=='A')
        {
            array[i]=A;
        }
        else if(letra=='b' || letra=='B')
        {
            array[i]=B;
        }
        else if(letra=='c' || letra=='C')
        {
            array[i]=C;
        }
        else if(letra=='d' || letra=='D')
        {
            array[i]=D;
        }
        else if(letra=='e' || letra=='E')
        {
            array[i]=E;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En tu ejemplo de uso, `palabra`tiene 4 caracteres, mientras que el ciclo for hace variar a i desde 0 hasta 4 (que son 5 iteraciones); y si te fijas en la definición de std::basic_string::at (por ejemplo en http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) verás por qué la excepción. Tendrías que usar un debugger y recorrer el programa paso a paso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, problema solucionado :)

Comment: ¿Debería cerrar la pregunta?

Comment: O quizá mejor, ¿por qué no escribes una respuesta? (está muy bien dar una respuesta a la pregunta que uno hizo)

Comment: @asdasdasd escribir la respuesta te correspondería a ti... la has escrito en forma de comentario y ahora lo suyo sería que la plasmases formalmente como una respuesta